# Trouble using fscanf to read coordinates in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coordinates, scanf

I know similar questions have been asked but none of them seemed to solve my problem. I get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when I run my code.

The first line in "data.dat" has the total number of points in the file and the next lines have the point coordinates (in 2 dimensions). I'm using `fgets` to read the first line and after that I'm using `fscanf` to read the next lines.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.dat","r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error");
    }

    int number;
    char str[3];

    fgets(str, 3, fp);
    number = atoi(str); // number of points to read from the file
    printf("number of lines: %d\n", number);

    // defining matrix to hold points
    float *P = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*2*number);

    int i = 0;
    while(i < number){
        int ret = fscanf(fp, "%f%f", P[i*number + 1], P[i*number + 2]);
        printf("%f  %f", P[i*number + 1], P[i*number + 2]);
        if (ret == 2){
            i++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this gives me no errors but it does give me the following warnings:

```
polynom.c: In function ‘main’:
polynom.c:32:24: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float*’,but argument 3 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]

int ret = fscanf(fp, "%f%f", P[i*number + 1], P[i*number + 2]);
                    ^
polynom.c:32:24: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 4 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
```

Which I don't really get because I did define argument 3 as float.

I run the code with a command line variable so the Segmentation fault is not because of that.

Comment: If you're scanning three digit numbers you have a very big problem in that your character array is exactly 3 bytes long.  You must allow for a null termination or your atoi is going to run past the bounds.

Comment: Please post some sample input data as well as trying to describe it.

Comment: Code is passing a `float` to `fscanf()`.  `fscanf()` does not need to know the _value_ of a `float`, it needs to know the _address_ of a `float` in which to store the result.  Use `fscanf(fp, "%f%f", &P[i*number + 1] ...`  (Add `&`)  Note: many other issues too

Comment: @chux that makes sense. Thanks. I'll try it when I get home. Can you comment on the other issues to? I'm new to C and there's a lot I need to learn...

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings.  Then fix the warnings.  After all, the compiler knows the C language much better than us humans and humans are fallible. Suggest reading the man page for fscanf() which will tell you (amongst other things) that the variables must be pointer.

Comment: suggest using a debugger, like 'gdb' to step through the code to determine exactly which line resulted in a seg fault event.  Then you can examine that line (and proceeding events) to determine the cause of the seg fault event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30404076/2410359) well answered the major issue.

Below are additional points.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Check argc 
    if (argc < 1) Print_Error_And Quit();
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.dat","r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error");
    }

    int number;
    char str[3];

    // avoid naked magic numbers
    // fgets(str, 3, fp);
    fgets(str, sizeof str, fp);
    number = atoi(str); // number of points to read from the file
    printf("number of lines: %d\n", number);

    // defining matrix to hold points
    // No need for cast, avoid mis-match type/variable
    // float *P = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float)*2*number);
    float *P = malloc(2*number * sizeof *P);

    int i = 0;
    while(i < number){
        // int ret = fscanf(fp, "%f%f", P[i*number + 1], P[i*number + 2]);
        // reform
        int ret = fscanf(fp, "%f%f", &P[2*i], &P[2*i + 1]);
        // printf("%f  %f", P[i*number + 1], P[i*number + 2]);
        printf("%f  %f ", P[2*i], P[2*i + 1]);
        if (ret == 2){
            i++;
        }
        else {
          Likely_Should_Exit_Loop();
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
while (2 == fscanf(fp, "%f%f", &P[i], &P[i+1]) {
    i += 2;
    if (i >= number*2)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `"%lf"` specifier, if your variables are `double`, and you must pass the address of the variable to `scanf()` not the variable itself, like this

```
double value;

if (scanf("%lf", &value) == 1) 
{   /*        ^   ^ */
    /*        |   the address of operator. */
    /*       the correct speficier for `double' */
    fprintf(stdout, "%lf\n", value);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm  `float *P`?  Its an address issue, not `float` v. `double`

Answer (score 0):

the malloc line is returning  a pointer to an area that is large enough to hold 'number*2' floats.  sound about right, but will not actually work correctly as there is no differentiation between one float and the next.

Suggest

```
struct twoFloat
{
    float float1;
    float float2;
};
```

then

```
struct twoFloat* P = malloc(sizeof(struct twoFloat)*number);
if ( NULL == P ) { // handle error and exit }

// implied else, malloc successful
....
```

then

```
    int ret = fscanf(fp, "%f%f", &P[i].float1, &P[i].float2);
    if (ret != 2) { // handle error and exit }

    // implied else, fscanf successful

    printf("%f  %f", P[i].float1, P[i].float2);
    i++;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "there is no differentiation between one float and the next". Can you calirfy? Thanks.